# Visual Basic - function to check if number is binary or not

Tags: vb.net

Im code newbie and im stuck with this code. It appears that i always get True as response from this function. What am i doing wrong ?

```
    Private Function binary() As Boolean
    Dim number, temp As Integer
    Dim status As Boolean
    TextBox1.Text = number
    status = True

    While (True)
        If (number = 0) Then
            Exit While
        Else
            temp = number Mod 10
            If (temp > 1) Then
                status = False
                Exit While
            End If
            number = number / 10
        End If
    End While

    Return status

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your assignment the wrong way around:

```
TextBox1.Text = number
```

With this, `number` will always be 0, its initial value, so your `While` loop exits immediately, every time.  It should be:

```
number = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
```

Or better yet, pass it in as a parameter to the function:

```
Private Function binary(number as Integer) As Boolean
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim status As Boolean

    status = True

    While (True)
        If (number = 0) Then
            Exit While
        Else
            temp = number Mod 10
            If (temp > 1) Then
                status = False
                Exit While
            End If
            number = number / 10
        End If
    End While

    Return status
End Function
```

Then:

```
Dim isBinary as Boolean
isBinary = binary(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: I know that im not suppose to do it this way but (since i cant do it in any other) i must give you some credit  so **big thank you James**.